# Escaping chars with GREP

Tags: unix, grep

I am using shell to search for a specific string withing PHP files on a server. The string is

> [...]

Normally I would use something like:

> grep "my string" *.php

but it does not work with these characters. Do I need to escape them? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[", ".", and "]" are special characters so they all need to be escaped.

`grep \[\.\.\.\] *.php`

Comment: Hmm, much easier then I was thinking... I went with greg -F "..." *.php  Thx.